# Is there good library to do nonnegative matrix factorization (NMF) fast?

Tags: python, c++, pca, matrix-factorization, nmf

I have a sparse matrix whose shape is **570000*3000**.  I tried [nima](http://nimfa.biolab.si/) to do NMF (using the default nmf method, and set `max_iter` to 65). However, I found nimfa very slow. Have anyone used a faster library to do NMF?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have used [`libNMF`](http://www.univie.ac.at/rlcta/software/) before. It's written in C and is very fast. There is a [paper](http://www.cai.sk/ojs/index.php/cai/article/view/161/136) documenting the algorithm and code.

The paper also lists several alternative packages for NMF (in bunch of different languages (which I have copied here for future reference).

- The Mathworks [3, 33]

  - Matlab
  - http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/nnmf.
- Cemgil [5]

  - Matlab
  - http://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~cemgil/bnmf
- Cichocki et al. [6]

  - Matlab
  - http://www.bsp.brain.riken.jp/ICALAB/nmflab.
- Cichocki et al. [7]

  - Matlab
  - http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470746661.html
- Hansen et al. [14]

  - Matlab
  - http://isp.imm.dtu.dk/toolbox/nmf/index.html
- Hoyer [16]

  - Matlab
  - http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/phoyer/software.html
- Kim et al. [19]

  - Matlab
  - http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/dmkim/Source/software/nnma/index.html
- Lin [25]

  - Matlab/Python
  - http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/nmf/index.html
- Schmidt et al. [30]

  - Matlab
  - http://mikkelschmidt.dk/index.php?id=2
- Gaujoux [10]

  - R
  - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html
- Liu [26]

  - R
  - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMFN/index.html
- Battenberg et al. [2](http://www.cai.sk/ojs/index.php/cai/article/view/161/136)

  - Python
  - http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ericb
- Schmitt et al. [31]

  - Python
  - http://www.procoders.net/?p=409
- Dhillon et al. [8]

  - C++
  - http://www.kyb.mpg.de/bs/people/suvrit/work/progs/nnma.html
- Greene et al. [13]

  - C++
  - http://mlg.ucd.ie/nmf
- Pathak et al. [28]

  - C++
  - http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/152
- Wang et al. [34]

  - C++
  - http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/7/175

Disclaimer: I have not tried any of these other packages (aside from MATLAB's).

Comment: As an update for other people finding this via Google:
**Mlpack** is a nice, fast, modern C++ Machine Learning library and they have a Module called "AMF - Alternative Matrix Factorization", which also has a few NMF algorithms: http://www.mlpack.org/docs/mlpack-2.0.1/doxygen.php?doc=namespacemlpack_1_1amf.html

Comment: Most of the links in this answer are broken. Again a great example of why software recommendations don't fit the SO model.

Comment: I just released a very fast NMF implementation in the RcppML R package. It makes use of the Eigen C++ library and is extensively optimized.  It's on CRAN:  `install.packages("RcppML")`. I will be maintaining and developing it for a long time.